# Aws cli - Role chaining - Use a master role in primary account to assume a secondary role in other account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, assume-role

I need to assume a temp role in a secondary account from a primary account. For primary account I already have a role which has an assume role policy for the temp role in secondary role. But when I am executing the command

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn ${primaryRoleArn} --role-session-name ${awsProfile}
```

I am getting this error

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:user/primary is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::secondaryAccount:role/secondary_role
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be attempting to assume the role as IAM user `primary`. Is that what you intended to do?

Comment: @jarmod Yes that is exactly I intent to do

Comment: Your IAM user doesn't have permission to assume that secondary role, as the error message indicates. Your question seems to suggest that you have an IAM role in the primary account (not an IAM user) which has an assume role policy for the temp role in secondary account. Probably best for you to include your policies. Also, re-read [IAM Tutorial: Delegate access across AWS accounts using IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your credentials in your ~/.aws/credentials file must be explicitly allowed to assume this role. So in primary role trust policy, you must add your username to allowed assumption.

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${AccountId}:user/${AwsUserName}"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
]
```